# Why if I'm the admin on the account I can't apply updates?

Tags: windows-7

I've been trying to apply some updates to a program on my computer.  The first updates I was able to apply with no problem, but now it's telling me I need admin permission to continue.  I am using an admin account.  What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Are these Windows Updates you're having troubles with?  Which ones? Are you using the in-built Windows Update, or some other mechanism (like installing the manually)?  What exactly do you mean by "it's telling me"?  What's the message that pops up?  What are the options offered?

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 7, you *never* just have implicit administrative privileges, even when logged in with the administrator account.  Running with an administrative account only gives you the right to *elevate* a specific process to that level, but *everything* runs under standard privileges by default.

If you are not prompted for elevation automatically, you can right click on the program and choose the "`Run as administrator`" option to explicitly start the program with administrative rights.

Comment: *never* is a strong word. Your statement is only true is UAC is turned on.

Comment: Since UAC is on by default and it is clear the OP is unaware of UAC, then it is safe to assume UAC is a factor.